# Convert pandas dataframe date and time string into datetime

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyspark

I have a table like

```
| name | time1                   | time2                   |
| ---- | ----------------------- | ----------------------- |
| one  | 10/18/2011 07:38:19 PM  | 10/18/2008 07:40:30 PM  |
| two  | 09/15/2006 08:40:21 AM  | 09/15/2002 08:45:26 AM  |
```

I am trying to convert columns time1 and time2 from string into datetime using the pandas `to_datetime`, from researching around it should be:

`new_df = pd.to_datetime(df['time1'], format='MM/dd/yyyy %I:%M:%S %p')`

However I keep getting this error no matter how I try using the to_datetime:

`ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool`

Can anyone point me the right way?

Comment: Try with: `new_df = pd.to_datetime(df['time1'], format='MM/dd/yyyy %I:%M:%S %p',errors='coerce')` ?

Comment: Still same "ValueError: Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions."

Comment: Probably the error is not on that statement then...

Comment: I see the pyspark tag on the question, are you looking for a pyspark solution as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to convert the string (note change to the `format` argument of `pd.to_datetime`):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'name': ['one', 'two'],
    'time1': ['10/18/2011 07:38:19 PM', '09/15/2006 08:40:21 AM'],
    'time2': ['10/18/2008 07:40:30 PM', '09/15/2002 08:45:26 AM']
})
pd.to_datetime(df['time1'], format='%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

0   2011-10-18 19:38:19
1   2006-09-15 08:40:21
Name: time1, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: I still have the same "Cannot convert column into bool" error, I think it's something related to do with pyspark and the to_datetime function

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data (say, 10 lines)?  It would be best if other people on SO could copy/paste your data directly into Python.